# How to pdb Python code with input?

Tags: python

I'm debugging Python code with pdb.
The code need input from stdin, like:

```
python -m pdb foo.py < bar.in
```

Then the pdb will accept the bar.in as commands.
How to tell pdb that the input is for foo.py and not for pdb?

Answer (score 3):

Well, this is a tweak to Aaron's answer, but I think it misses the point in that you want to interactively debug at some point, right?  This works but the program exits before you get a chance to debug.

```
(echo cont;cat bar.in) | python -m pdb foo.py
```

I think if you can edit foo.py, do `import pdb` then at the interesting point in foo.py do `pdb.set_trace()`, and just run `python foo.py` without the `-m pdb` and give it bar.in normally

```
python foo.py < bar.in
```

Answer (score 1):

A kind of gross work around is to put `cont` at the beginning of `bar.in`:

```
cont
one
two
three
four


aaron@ares ~$ python -m pdb cat.py < bar.in 
> ~/cat.py(1)<module>()
-> import sys
(Pdb) one
two
three
four
The program finished and will be restarted
> ~/cat.py(1)<module>()
-> import sys
(Pdb)
```